# Reuse of space after TRUNCATE TABLE by other tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm considering truncating a large table in my production database. It is full of log data that is not actually needed. After searching around the internet, I've learnt the following points.

- How TRUNCATE is different to DELETE.
- That space freed up is not released back to the file system.
- That you can SHRINK the database to free up disk space, however, you need to be careful and wise about doing so.
- That if the table that I TRUNCATE grows again, it will reuse the space freed up.

My question is this:

*If I do truncate my table, will the growth of other tables re-use that space freed up, and hence save disk space in the long term?*

The reason I ask that is that it would be good if useful new content in other tables used this space, and it prevented growth on the disk (at least until the reused space is exhausted).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do truncate my table, will the growth of other tables re-use that space freed up, and hence save disk space in the long term?

Yup, which is one reason why `SHRINK`ing is silly - it's just an additional wasteful operation to release the free space back into the disk when future growths are possible. Truncating releases the space internally to the database, within the data file, making it applicable for re-use by other internal growth within that same database. I.e. as other tables grow, if there's space available inside the data file from a previous truncate, it'll be re-used to accommodate that growth before having to pull more space from the disk itself.

The `unused` column in the result set for [`sp_spaceused`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will tell you how much space is currently available inside of the data file that's applicable for growth operations without having to pull from the disk itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response J.D.

I did my TRUNCATE table command and looked at the before and after of the `sp_spaceused` command. That command returns two different rows. I notice that the `unallocated space` column in the first results did show a big increase, consistent with the amount of data that should have been freed up. The `unused` column in the second result stayed much the same. Perhaps when you mentioned the `unused` column you meant `unallocated_space`?